# return array based on search criteria

Tags: php, css, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => Product 1
        [color] => green
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [1] => Product 12
        [color] => red
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [1] => Product 3
        [color] => blue
    )
)
```

and I would like to be able to filter out data based on color value. Function like:

```
function filter_data($array, $color) {

}
```

where I can pass `$array` and `$color` arguments as strings, than result would be an array with all items containing color blue.

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably take a look at how to use [foreach loops](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). This will be *very* important to learn if you want to learn PHP.

```
function filter_data($array, $color) {
  $results = array();
  foreach ($array as $data) {
    if ($data['color'] == $color) {
      $results[] = $data;
    }
  }
  return $results;
}
```

This function simply iterates over all values in `$array` and checks each sub-array's `color` to see if it matches the given `$color`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data looks like this:

```
$data = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Product 1', 'color' => 'green'),
    array('id' => 2, 1 => 'Product 12', 'color' => 'red'),
    array('id' => 3, 1 => 'Product 3', 'color' => 'blue'),
);
```

We can loop through it, and only return an array based on `color=__desired_color__`.

```
$final = array();
foreach ($data as $dat) {
    if ($dat['color'] == "blue") {
        $final[] = $dat;
    }
}
```

I hope you know how to make this a function. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Heres a function for ya....

It lets you input the array, the key/field you wanna filter, and the search term you wanna search for...

```
/*
*@param $arr = array  //array of your choosing
*@param $field  string  //key value of array to search through 
*@param $item   string  //Search term
*@return array  //returns filtered array
*/

function search($arr, $field, $item){
 $result = array();
 foreach ($arr as $val) {
     if ($val[$field] == $item) {
    $result[] = $val;
  }
 }
 return $result;
 }
```

Then just use it like so...

```
search($yourarray, "color","blue");
```

Comment: Your var $result; does not do anything it should be $final instead